# Calculating window width minus an exact amount of pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How would I code this correctly, the (window.innerWidth minus 80px) part:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div> 

<style>
#myDiv{
        float-right;
        right: (window.innerWidth minus 80px);
        width: 40vw;
        height 200px;
        background-color: #333333;
}
</style>
```

I have a reason for doing it exactly this way. [JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/cwuh4hu4/)

Comment: can't use javascript in css...look up `css calc()`

Comment: Like this `right: calc(100% - 80px)`

Comment: right: calc(100% - 80px) does not seem to work for positioning

Comment: width: calc(100% - 80px) does work, but not right: calc(100% - 80px)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/cwuh4hu4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write

```
right: calc(100vw - 80px);
```

plus you have to add `position: relative;` for the `right` parameter to have any effect at all: https://jsfiddle.net/78hd0hf1/1/

That also works if `#myDiv` is nested in one or several wrappers which are narrower than the window width (which can be a problem when using 100% instead of 100vw).

Comment: `#myDiv` needs to have `position: relative;`  for the `right` parameter to be effective at all: https://jsfiddle.net/78hd0hf1/1/

Answer (score 0):

`right: calc(100% - 80px);` ought to work.

Comment: right: calc(100% - 80px) does not seem to work for positioning

Comment: width: calc(100% - 80px) does work, but not right: calc(100% - 80px)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/cwuh4hu4

Comment: @Eddy Use `position: absolute` to get this behavior.